# Add VSDX file to a DOCX file using Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, docx, visio

I have a file with .VSDX extension, i want to add it to the file with .Docx extension using Java. The generated byte[] will later be send in response where i can download it and edit the visio file later.

Comment: which api do you use to open vsdx and docx files in Java? have you tried something?

Comment: i tried Aspose but i am  not able to merge it to the docx file. Also the help which i got from Aspose website was it converts the VSDX file to PDF and then try to merge, in this case the response docx file the diagram will be non editable